# convert String to int return NumberFormatException

Tags: android, exception, numberformatexception, valueconverter

i from API I receive next string:

```
String userId = "4463570100035744";
```

I need to convert it to int, so I tried next code:

```
try {
     int id = Integer.parseInt(userId);
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I still catch exeption....

what can be the reason?

Comment: try  Integer.parseInt(userId.trim());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

REASON: value is outside the range of an int

ACTION: You must use Long and not Integer .Use a long/Long instead.

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE =  2147483647
Integer.MIN_VALUE = -2147483648

Long.MAX_VALUE =  9223372036854775807
Long.MIN_VALUE = -9223372036854775808
```

Answer (score 0):

you take variable `userId` as String and you put integer value in it and then you parse it to convert in integer. Your mistake is you put integer value in String variable `userId`.
You need to put it like this :

```
String userId = "4463570100035744";
```

One more thing keep the size of variable in mind. I think value is too large then the size of `int`.
And now you edited your question, after people post answers to your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

4463570100035744 is too large a number for an Int32 variable. You could consider using a `long` variable type.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the docs for the Java primitive types to select the appropriate type for your variable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

The primitive types available to store a number like your userId are:

- `byte` (1 byte)     
   Range: −128 to 127
- `short` (2 bytes)   
   Range: −32768 to 32767
- `int` (4 bytes)     
   Range: −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
- `float` (4 bytes)   
   Range: 3.4e−038 to 3.4e+038
- `long` (8 bytes)    
   Range: 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,755,807
- `double` (8 bytes)  
   Range: 1.7e−308 to 1.7e+038

Notice how your int is `4463570100035744` which compared to `int` has a difference of 4,463,567,952,552,097.

Your id variable would be best suited for a `long`.

```
try 
{
    long id = Long.parseLong(userId);
    System.out.println("long id = " + id);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
{
    System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
}
```